# combining mysql query SUM() result using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables

```
table1 : date | uid | value_in
table2 : date | uid | value_out
```

each day, every uid will receive a balance value for both in and out, regardless of the number of transaction/records

what I want to do is to combine the query result to be like this

```
date | uid | value_in | value_out | (value_in-value_out) as balance
```

however, when I do this query

```sql
SELECT 
  a.date,
  a.uid,
  SUM(a.value_in),
  SUM(b.value_out),
  (SUM(a.value_in)-SUM(b.value_out)) AS balance
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.date=b.date AND a.uid=b.uid
GROUP BY a.date, a.uid
```

it produce invalid result (the SUM is doubled or tripled)
how should I modify my query so it does not produce doubled result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First build the sum, then join. Like this:

```
SELECT i.uid
      ,i.date
      ,i.v_in
      ,COALESCE(o.v_out, 0) AS v_out
      ,(i.v_in - COALESCE(o.v_out, 0)) AS balance
FROM (
    SELECT date
          ,uid
          ,SUM(value_in) AS v_in
    FROM   table1
    GROUP  BY 1,2
    ) i
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT date
          ,uid
          ,SUM(value_out) AS v_out
    FROM   table2
    GROUP  BY 1,2
    ) o USING (date, uid)
```

The way you had it, every `value_in` would be combined with every matching `value_out`, thereby multiplying the numbers. You must aggregate first and then you join **one** in-sum with **one** out-sum and everything is groovy. Or is it?

What happens if there are no `value_in` or `value_out` for a given `(date, uid)`? Or only `value_in` Or just `value_out`? Your query will fail.

I improved by using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `[INNER] JOIN`, but what you really want is a `FULL OUTER JOIN` - one of the missing features in MySQL.

You can either provide a list of days in a separate table and `LEFT JOIN` both tables to it, or you can work around the missing feature with two times `LEFT JOIN` and `UNION`. [See here for an example](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/).

**Or** you could multiply your `value_out` by `-1` UNION both tables together and build one sum.

But you **still** would not get a row for a day without any `value_in` or `value_out`, which violates your description.

So, the **only clean solution** is to have a table with all `(date, uid)` you want in the result and `LEFT JOIN` the sums of `table1` and `table2` to it, or `UNION ALL` the three (negative `table2`) in a sub-select and then sum up.

Comment: whoa, it's working. Better and faster than INNER JOIN, I need to learn this kind of query. Thanks

Comment: @skeith: I added some improvements and fixes. You may want to have a look.

Comment: yes, thanks again for the improvement and fixes you provide, it is more than what I expected, will learn from it (I find it too advanced for me)

Answer (score 0):

What will be result if you try this

```
SELECT 
  a.date,
  a.uid,
  SUM(a.value_in),
  SUM(b.value_out),
  SUM(a.value_in-b.value_out) AS balance 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.date=b.date AND a.uid=b.uid
GROUP BY a.date, a.uid
```

`SUM(a.value_in-b.value_out) AS balance` should be logically same as `(SUM(a.value_in)-SUM(b.value_out)) AS balance` but maybe not to mysql

Comment: I've tried this query too before posting my question and still produce similar invalid results

Comment: than you probably have negative values in second table

Comment: @MilanJaric: Read my answer for an explanation why this fails.

Comment: Yes I got it, I realized at the end that there is not equal number of of rows in both tables for each par date, uid. Good thinking @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: as I explain on the question that the transaction records may not be the same for each in and out. however, it should follow one rule, that in-out should be 0 (zero)

Comment: @skeith: this query does *not* fail because the number of records per (date, uid) in both tables differ. When joining the tables the matching rows form a Cartesian product, which fails as soon as there is *more than one record* for any (date, uid) in any of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  a.date,
  a.uid,
  SUM(a.value_in),
  SUM(b.value_out),
  SUM(a.value_in-b.value_out) AS balance 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.date=b.date AND a.uid=b.uid
GROUP BY a.date, a.uid`enter code here`
```