# how to get sum of two tables linked to a third

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, postgresql

would any sql Wizards out there help with with this question:
suppose I have 3 tables:

```
tbltype        tblvalue               tblcost
id  | type     id  | val | typeid     id  | cost| typeid
----------     ------------------     ------------------ 
1   | aaa      1   | 3   | 1          1   | 5   | 1 
2   | bbb      2   | 2   | 1          2   | 3   | 1
               3   | 2   | 2          3   | 1   | 2
               4   | 1   | 2          4   | 4   | 2
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT t.type, SUM(val), SUM(cost)
FROM
    tbltype t 
    LEFT JOIN tblcost c ON (c.typeid = t.id)
    LEFT JOIN tblvalue v ON (v.typeid = t.id)
GROUP BY t.type;
```

I get the wrong value of

```
type | SUM(val) | SUM(cost)
---------------------------
aaa  | 10       | 16
bbb  | 6        | 10
```

how do I get the right value of:

```
type | SUM(val) | SUM(cost)
---------------------------
aaa  | 5        | 8
bbb  | 3        | 5
```

and why does sql behaves like that?

Comment: Very similar question for mysql: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7989160/939860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see why, take the group and sums out of your query and look at what it's summing:

```
SELECT t.type, val, cost
FROM
    tbltype t 
    LEFT JOIN tblcost c ON (c.typeid = t.id)
    LEFT JOIN tblvalue v ON (v.typeid = t.id)
```

You'll see you have each possible combination of the rows from tblcost and tblvalue in the output-- this means some of them get counted multiple times when you sum them.

You need to aggregate tblcost and tblvalue separately. You can then join them back onto tbltype. Gavin's answer already shows one way to do that. Another way is:

```
SELECT t.type, COALESCE(cost, 0) AS cost, COALESCE(val, 0) AS val
FROM tbltype t
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(cost) AS cost, typeid FROM tblcost GROUP BY typeid) tc
       ON tc.typeid = t.id
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(val) AS val, typeid FROM tblvalue GROUP BY typeid) tv
       ON tv.typeid = t.id
```

... which may or may not perform differently (and may or may not be better) depending on which database engine you're actually using.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.type,
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(v.val) FROM tblvalue AS v WHERE v.typeid = t.id),0) AS val,
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(c.cost) FROM tblcost AS c WHERE c.typeid = t.id),0) AS cost
  FROM tbltype AS t;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got enough answers suggesting how to solve your problem correctly. You've also got @araqnid's answer that helps you to see why you get such results in the end. The only thing that remains for me seems to be to explain the behaviour itself, as per your request.

Basically, the reason behind such behaviour is the fact that the second join is performed not on `tbltype` and `tblvalue`, as one might think, but on the result of the join between `tbltype` and `tblcost`, on the one hand, and the `tblvalue` table, on the other. Now, the first join produces duplicates of `t.id`, because they match the second table more than once:

```
tbltype        tblcost
id  type       id  cost  typeid       t.id  t.type  c.id  c.cost  c.typeid
--  ----   ×   --  ----  ------   =   ----  ------  ----  ------  --------
1   aaa        1   5     1            1     aaa     1     5       1
1   bbb        2   3     1            1     aaa     2     3       1
               3   1     2            2     bbb     3     1       2
               4   4     2            2     bbb     4     4       2
```

The second join produces more duplicates, because:

- *every* occurrence of `t.id` from the first join's result set is getting matched against `v.typeid`

and

- the `typeid` values in the `tblvalue` table are duplicated too.

As a result, rows from both `tblcost` and `tblvalue` get duplicated in the process:

```
                                           tblvalue        
t.id  t.type  c.id  c.cost  c.typeid       id  val  typeid  
----  ------  ----  ------  --------       --  ---  ------  
1     aaa     1     5       1          ×   1   3    1        =
1     aaa     2     3       1              2   2    1       
2     bbb     3     1       2              3   2    2       
2     bbb     4     4       2              4   1    2       


    t.id  t.type  c.id  c.cost  c.typeid  v.id  v.val  v.typeid
    ----  ------  ----  ------  --------  ----  -----  --------
    1     aaa     1     5       1         1     3      1
    1     aaa     1     5       1         2     2      1
=   1     aaa     2     3       1         1     3      1
    1     aaa     2     3       1         2     2      1
    2     bbb     3     1       2         3     2      2
    2     bbb     3     1       2         4     1      2
    2     bbb     4     4       2         3     2      2
    2     bbb     4     4       2         4     1      2
```

The only way out for you seems to be to aggregate each table separately. That doesn't necessarily imply separate queries, just separate *sub*queries, as you can now see from the answers.

Answer (score 0):

QUickest solution is to split the query in two

```
SELECT
    `tbltype`.`type`, SUM(val)
FROM
    tbltype
     LEFT JOIN `tblvalue` ON (`tblvalue`.`typeid` = `tbltype`.`id`)
GROUP BY `tbltype`.`type`;
```

and

```
SELECT
    `tbltype`.`type`, SUM(cost)
FROM
    tbltype
     LEFT JOIN `tblcost` ON (`tblcost`.`typeid` = `tbltype`.`id`)
GROUP BY `tbltype`.`type`;
```

Comment: yes, I get correct result when I split the query but i need it to show on one table. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select t1.id, val, cost from (
    select t.id, sum(val) as val
    from tbltype t
    join tblvalue v on t.id = v.typeId
    group by t.id
) t1
join (
    select t.id, sum(cost) as cost
    from tbltype t
    inner join tblcost c on t.id = c.typeid
    group by t.id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

... or if `tblcost` and `tblvalue` are related by `id`:

```
select t.id, sum(val) as val, sum(cost) as cost
from tbltype t
inner join tblcost c on t.id = c.typeid
inner join tblvalue v on c.id = v.id
group by t.id
```